# How do I keep logo in a window title of a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

Hello Everyone,

I want to add my company logo before the title of the window. Please check the image below, I just want to add my company logo as the Gmail logo in the tab name.

I am using 
`title=div(img(src="logo.ico","Company name")` but that doesn't do the job. I appreciate any ideas here.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: It is an R shiny Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been addressed in other questions, but this is how I've done it. The following code goes in the first line of your UI call:

```
fluidPage(list(tags$head(HTML('<link rel="icon", href="MyIcon.png", 
                                 type="image/png" />'))),
             div(style="padding: 1px 0px; width: '100%'",
                 titlePanel(
                   title="", windowTitle="MyWindowTitle"
                 )
             ),
Replace with other UI elements...
)
```

And then include the icon in a folder called www/ in your app directory.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. I searched for the same here but I couldn't find. Anyway thank you

Comment: I also looked for the post that I found this solution in but couldn't find it either...